# Using "is" operator with a default(T) on the left side

Tags: c#, .net, operators, compiler-warnings

I have an abstract class call AEntity, this is the base class for an entity in my game.

I also have a couple interfaces to "mark" the entities, for example:

```
interface EffectEntity<T> where T : AEntity
{
    void UpdateEffect();
}
```

In a part of my program, I have a `List<AEntity>` and a method called add.

This list cannot hold an `EffectEntity`. Here is my code for the add method:

```
if (Item is EffectEntity<T>)
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot add an effectEntity to the still entities");
}
else allStillEntities.Add(Item);
```

And this does not throw any errors, but when I change the line `if(Item is EffectEntiy<T>)` to `if(default(T) is EffectEntity<T>)`, it gives warning CS0148: "The given expression is never of the provided type `('EffectEntity<T>')` type"

Why is this? shouldn't they produce the same result?
Yeah sure, the version that uses `Item` on the left side is probably more efficient, but I am still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default(T)` is going to be `null`, and the compiler knows this.  [`null` isn't an instance of `EffectEntity<T>`](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/30/what-the-meaning-of-is-is/), so it knows that it will be `false`.

`Item` may or may not be `null`, an `EffectEntity<T>` instance, or some other type of object.

Comment: Alright, but why will it be null?

Comment: Because it's a reference type, and that's the default value for all reference types.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks! So if I were to do ` int i = default(int) ` it would give a non-null value? And does this mean any reference type is nullable (As in without T?)?

Comment: @OptimisticPeach you can run that code and see for yourself what `i` will be in that case.  Yes, all reference types are nullable.